# Prevent Xcode 9 from opening blank unresponsive windows

Tags: xcode, xcode9, xcode9.1

I've updated to Xcode 9 (9.1 release (not beta) to be more specific but I don't remember if this issue started with 9 or 9.1).

I've started getting weird empty unresponsive windows that sometimes do not respond to close commands (see it compared to a normal window):

[image]

It's completely empty, happens randomly, and not tied to a specific project or file type. It happens through different projects, source codes, storyboards etc.

As an iOS developer this started to become extremely counter-productive. How can I prevent this from happening?